# Hacked email or total accident

Tags: facebook, gmail

I have a Facebook account which I look at occasionaly and access via the Facebook app. However whilst reading my emails I tried to access it from n email had they had sent me. I clicked the link which opened up the Facebook log in page. The boxs were complete already so I loged in, but it was somebody else's account. It was a family member who is not my Facebook friend and has never used my phone or iPad. This person gave me an old laptop 6 months ago to practice how to use them as I'm new to computing. I used it for a short time but grew fed up as I didn't know how to use properly. Can anybody advise me on how my emails link up to her Facebook Acc and what action I should take. Cheers, Kevin

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you got a notification from Facebook that required you to sign in, then at the login page it autofilled the form fields with the family member's credentials that she neglected to remove from the web browser before giving you the laptop. If that was the case, then note that following a link to Facebook will not pre-populate the form on your behalf, although browsers offer that feature as a convenience to users who do not share a machine with others.